# Calculate totals of field based on current fiscal year only - SQL

Tags: sql

I have seen many examples regarding calculating the sum of fields using the fiscal year, but I can not find one that fits my needs.  What I am trying to do is get just the current fiscal year totals for a field using SQL Query.  The fields I have is userid, startdate, total_hours, and missed_hours.  Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT    
userid,    
SUM(total_hours) - SUM(missed_hours) AS hours    
FROM mytable    
GROUP BY userid
```

This works great, but all I need is the total number of hours for the current fiscal year for each of the userid's.  Our fiscal year runs from July to June.  I only need the current fiscal year and I need it to start over again this coming July.

Comment: startdate is the "date" field that will be used to figure in the query for the fiscal year.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is SQLServer, try:

```
SELECT userid, SUM(total_hours) - SUM(missed_hours) AS hours    
FROM mytable
WHERE startdate >= cast( cast(year(dateadd(MM,-6,getdate())) as varchar(4)) + 
                         '-07-01' as date ) and
      startdate <  cast( cast(year(dateadd(MM, 6,getdate())) as varchar(4)) + 
                         '-07-01' as date )
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: There was a typo in my query that I have now corrected - if you are using SQLServer, this should now work.

Comment: Just took out the extra "," in the second part of the where statement.  I had to change date to datetime.  This works for me.  Thanks!

Comment: In SQL Server you can also `CAST('2012' AS date)`, which would result in the date of `2012-01-01`. So, for instance, the beginning of the current fiscal year could also be found like this: `DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CAST(DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS date))`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a where clause:

```
FROM mytable
WHERE startdate >= '2011-07-01'
GROUP BY userid
```

Or with the start of the year dynamically:

```
where startdate >= dateadd(yy, datepart(yy, getdate())-2001, '2000-07-01')
```

Comment: I didn't donwvote you, and I know that is a simple fix, but op asked for fiscal year and said that their fiscal year runs from July to June

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    userid,
    SUM(total_hours) - SUM(missed_hours) AS hours
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    MONTH(startdate) BETWEEN 6 AND 7
    AND YEAR(startdate) IN (2011,2012)
GROUP BY userid
```

Answer (score 0):

For the solution, two additional information is needed

- the name of the date column
- the vendor type of RDBMS you are using

I supposed your date column is `date_col` and you are using MySQL

```
SELECT    
userid,    
SUM(total_hours) - SUM(missed_hours) AS hours    
FROM mytable    
WHERE date_col between STR_TO_DATE('01,7,2011','%d,%m,%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('01,7,2010','%d,%m,%Y')
GROUP BY userid
```